# Apache NiFi connection with Compass

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I  would like to know how to find the URL to connect Apache NiFi to MongoDB.
I am very new to Mongo.
I have  the below mentioned masked string with which I connect to compass

mongodb:://xxuser:xxxxxx@yy.yy.yyy:yyyyy/users?authSource=users&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false.

How do I find the string to connect to NiFi from compass and ingest the data from there?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi Ankur, your question is a bit confusing, so as far as I understand you want to store the data processed in NiFi to Mongo, right ?!! If so you can use a processor with name "PutMongoRecords/PutMongo".

Comment: Hi, you understood this part right. I need to put the records in Mongo DB. However, I don't have the connection string to use from NiFi to Mongo DB. I know the Port number of my company and the ip address as well where HDFS is hosted. However, I don't know how to form the  string

Comment: I have found out that I can use the same exact string in NiFi what I used in  compass to connect. I also used PutMongo Processor to connect and it worked with that.

Answer (score 0):

PutMongo processor is used to connect NiFi to MongoDb and I can directly ingest data in the store as well.

The string will go in MongoURI field of the processor and it will be the  same as of compass

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is something like this: `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/`

If no auth is required then: `mongodb://localhost:27017`